# Advancing to a specific keyboard Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios8

When making a custom keyboard for IOS8, the code to advance to the next keyboard is:

```
self.advanceToNextInputMode()
```

Is there a way to advance to either a certain keyboard or the previous keyboard?

**Edit**: The purpose of this function is to alternate between an uppercase and lowercase keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,it is not possible,apple is not provided any API's to move to previous keyboard or a particular keyboard.

You can manage uppercase and lowercase on same keyboard by changing the array's while making an extension,You can use one array for lowercase and one array for uppercase.

please refer the blog for the third party keyboards(App Keyboard Extension)

http://blog.mastersoftwaresolutions.com/ios-8-third-party-keyboards-using-app-extension/